# Using PHP cURL to downloading URL with special characters

Tags: php, curl, unicode, web-scraping

I'm trying to download the following URL `https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/vendita-asta-appartamento-genova-via-san-giovanni-d’acri-14-1360824` with PHP cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/vendita-asta-appartamento-genova-via-san-giovanni-d’acri-14-1360824');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$f = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $f;
```

but the server always returns an error page. Navigating the same URL in a web browser works fine. Manually comparing the HTML source returned by `curl_exec` with the HTML source in a web browser, the difference is immediately noticeable.

I tried to `utf8_decode()` the URL without success.

I cannot simply wrap the url 
in `urlencode()` because it will encode even normal characters like `:` and `/`.

That URLs are retrieved programmatically (scraping) and won't always have the same structure, so it would be difficult to split them and urlencode just some parts.

Btw, it seems that modern web browsers handle this case very well. There is a solution for that in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with:

```
function urlencode_parts($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $parts['path'] = implode('/', array_map('urlencode', explode('/', $parts['path'])));
    $url = new \http\Url($parts);
    return $url->toString();
}
```

using the package `\http\Url`, that replaces `http_build_url` function in newest PHP versions.

Seems that `file_get_contents` doesn't work too with special characters.

**Update 2018-05-09**: it seems fixed in cUrl 7.52.1

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is already encoded. Do not call `urlencode()` on it as that the reason you get 404, as server decodes only once. Just remove the call.

Answer (score 0):

**Parse the URL components, then encode them.**

the idea is to use `urlencode()` only on the path and query parts of the URL, leaving the initial segment alone. I believe that is what browsers do behind the scenes.

You can use `parse_url()` to split the URL into its components, escape the parts you need to (most likely path and query) and reassemble it. Someone even posted a function to reassemble the URL in the comments on the `parse_url()` [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/it/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: A bit hackish, splitting URL in parts, encoding them separately will work. I was just wondering if there is a more pretty way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
$urli=parse_url('https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/vendita-asta-appartamento-genova-via-san-giovanni-d’acri-14-1360824');
$url=urli['scheme'].'://'.$urli['host'].'/'.urlencode(ltrim('/',$urli['path'])).'?'.$urli['query'];
```

Comment: A bit hackish, splitting URL in parts, encoding them separately will work. I was just wondering if there is a more pretty way to do it.