# curl, how to download files with special characters?

Tags: php, curl

my downloading function:

```
public static function download($a)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $a);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $a= curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $a;
}
```

and given this link:

```
http://example.com/x.txt
```

is works well. But with a special case:

```
http://example.com/fájl/név/with ékezetek.txt
```

then its a "**400 - bad request.**" `curl_errno` is 22 then. How to download it then? urlencode is not OK since it encode the hostname itself.

EDIT: those url are given "outside", I have no influence of it!

Comment: Check your encoding.

Comment: So if you try to urlencode the file name only ?

Comment: rawurlencode() returns: http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ff%C3%A1jl%2Fn%C3%A9v%2Fwith%20%C3%A9kezetek.txt and urlencode() returns: http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ff%C3%A1jl%2Fn%C3%A9v%2Fwith+%C3%A9kezetek.txt both are incorrect result.

Comment: Have you tried with something like this?


`urlencode(utf8_encode($url))`

Comment: @MoisésMárquez not works either.

Comment: May be this link for you helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841468/using-php-curl-to-downloading-url-with-special-characters

Comment: I've created a file and use a command like this:

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/saßen.html");`

and works correctly. Which version of PHP and which server are you using?

Comment: @MoisésMárquez php 5.6.38, nginx/1.10.2

Comment: Can you try with PHP 7.X? I'm testing with PHP 7.3 and Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL and file_get_contents does not work with URL containing special character (accented letters, quotes, ...)

Solution:

```
$data = file_get_contents(urlEncode('http://www.test.com/file/file_planta_1ª.jpg'));

function urlEncode($url)
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $parts['path'] = implode('/', array_map('urlencode', explode('/', $parts['path'])));
    return $parts['scheme'].'://'.$parts['host'].$parts['path'];
}
```

Comment: If you need to add parameters:

```return $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . $parts['path'] . '?' . $parts['query'];```

Answer (score 1):

try to make a

```
base64_encode
```

of the data, and a

```
base64_decode
```

to get original data

Comment: the urls are given from the outside, I have no influence of it

Answer (score 1):

Improved [Andrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67614229/5181112).

One will get a better result using [rawurlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) function.

```php
function fileUrlEncode($url)
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $parts['path'] = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $parts['path'])));
    return $parts['scheme'].'://'.$parts['host'].$parts['path'];
}
```